# Duvida .NET usar informações no site value em webview2

Tags: .net, vb.net

Olá, tenho um programa que fiz para mim, no qual me ajuda no meu trabalho em agilziar, mas tive problemas com um tempo em preencher informações em um site https://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/laudosnew/requerimentos.php, ainda sou novato nesta parte, mas meu problema é o seguinte, neste site tento preencher os dados, usando codigo

```
        Dim CNPJ As String = "document.getElementByName('cnpj_empresa').value = '" & FrmAlvara.CNPJMaskedTextBox.Text & "'"
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(CNPJ)
```

mas ao executar no site ele não preencher o local, e parece que no site não tem o "value" quando preenche, utilizo em VB.net e WebView2, neste caso como consigo preencher o site automaticamente?

Answer (score -1):

Creio que a abordagem mais simples e menos trabalhosa seria você interceptar no network do seu navegador a requisição que o site faz quando envia as informações.

Eu fiz o preenchimento deixando o network do meu navegador aberto e consegui copiar a requisição, como abaixo:

[image: request efetuada para submeter as informações do form]

copiando o comando:

[image: copiando o comando curl]

o comando copiado é este abaixo. com ele, em qualquer terminal (que suporte o comando curl) você poderá fazer a mesma requisição que o navegador faria.

```
curl 'https://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/laudosnew/requerimentos.php' \
-X 'POST' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Host: venus.maringa.pr.gov.br' \
-H 'Origin: https://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15' \
-H 'Referer: https://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/laudosnew/requerimentos.php' \
-H 'Content-Length: 1216' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=14493f5ccee2b4b76b78f7b6ee427d0e' \
--data 'idtemprotocolo=455805&tiporeqlaudo=comum&razao=adfsadf&fantasia=asdfasdfasfd&tipopessoa=F&cpf_empresa=36419811074&cnpj_empresa=&cod_endereco=&endereco2=&num=&cep=&complemento=&zona=&quadra=2&data_data=02&lote=3&cad_imobiliario=e3322&bairro=&telefone=&resp_tec=&cons_classe=&cod_cnae1=&txt_cnae1=&class_cnae1=&cod_cnae2=&txt_cnae2=&class_cnae2=&cod_cnae3=&txt_cnae3=&class_cnae3=&cod_cnae4=&txt_cnae4=&class_cnae4=&cod_cnae5=&txt_cnae5=&class_cnae5=&cod_cnae6=&txt_cnae6=&class_cnae6=&cod_cnae7=&txt_cnae7=&class_cnae7=&cod_cnae8=&txt_cnae8=&class_cnae8=&cod_cnae9=&txt_cnae9=&class_cnae9=&cod_cnae10=&txt_cnae10=&class_cnae10=&cod_cnae11=&txt_cnae11=&class_cnae11=&cod_cnae12=&txt_cnae12=&class_cnae12=&cod_cnae13=&txt_cnae13=&class_cnae13=&cod_cnae14=&txt_cnae14=&class_cnae14=&cod_cnae15=&txt_cnae15=&class_cnae15=&cod_serv1=&txt_serv1=&cod_serv2=&txt_serv2=&cod_serv3=&txt_serv3=&cod_serv4=&txt_serv4=&ramo=teste&obs=teste&area=&tipoformal=S&aceite=S&escritorio_nome=&escritorio_fone=&escritorio_email=&escritorio_cpfcnpj=&escritorio_rg=&razao_requerente=&telefone_requerente=&cnpj_requerente=&cpf_requerente=&rg_requerente=&email_requerente=&endereco_requerente=&chk_ren_alv=1&chk_alt_raz=1&next01=Proximo+%3E%3E'
```

Com isso, você não precisará instanciar um navegador para preenchê-lo ( que certamente lhe colocará em vários apuros durante o preenchimento por programação ).

Esse comando curl é o comando mais básico em todos os terminais para executar uma requisição por linha de comando. Creio que seu esforço será muito menor construindo este comando, seja pelo c# ou por outra ferramenta e isso deixará você totalmente agnóstico a qualquer tipo de plataforma.

Outra alternativa seria utilizar ferramentas de teste de UI como o Selenium (https://www.selenium.dev) para fazer isso. Porém eu acho que isso seria muito mais complicado que simplesmente forjar requests.